# Run in opposite direction?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

[image]

I have this code that figures out the shortest distance between my white balls and my green balls.

When it's used by my green balls, they chase the white ones and turn them into green ones.

Is there a way to do the opposite of what my green balls do so my white ones run away? The green balls code is below:

```
private Vector3 FindClosestHuman()
{
    GameObject[] Humans = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Human");

    Transform bestTarget = null;
    float closestDistanceSqr = Mathf.Infinity;
    Vector3 currentPosition = this.transform.position;
    foreach (GameObject human in Humans)
    {
        Vector3 directionToTarget = human.transform.position - currentPosition;

        float dSqrToTarget = directionToTarget.sqrMagnitude;
        if (dSqrToTarget < closestDistanceSqr)
        {
            closestDistanceSqr = dSqrToTarget;
            bestTarget = human.transform;
        }
    }

    return bestTarget.position;
}

void Update ()
{
        infectionAgent.SetDestination(FindClosestHuman());
}
```

I've tried using transform.translate and Vector3 in the Update method but I just can't seem to get it to work...

Comment: If you did that and you cannot do the opposite means there is a lot of copy & paste in this code :D

Comment: @IgnacioSolerGarcia You are correct haha. The problem is that what I need to do now doesn't seem like it'd fit in that code and I don't know what the opposite of SetDestination is.

Comment: Can you be more specific? Do you want the balls to run away from the nearest player or something else?

Answer (score 1):

There is no opposite of `SetDestination` for Unity's `NavMeshAgent`.

That is: how you decide which direction to take at a fork when running *away* from something? Randomly? The one that gives the most distance? What if you can run in circles, is that better than running into a dead end, even if you stay closer to your away-from target? Does running towards your away-from target in order to reach a branch that lets you reach a farther-away destination allowed?

You need to figure out what "run away" means and write your own algorithm for that sort of navigation.